# Group By with Count ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, lambda

I am trying to make a simple record management app.
I want to get the total employee count per department. I have this so far.

```
return Context.Employees
    .GroupBy(e => e.DepartmentID)
    .Select(x => new { Employee = x.Count() });
```

But it gives me a red wiggly line which says that I may be missing a cast.

> Cannot implicitly convert type System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#> to System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<SimpleRMA.Models.Department>. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Here is my desired result:

```
DepartmentName | Employees 

Department1    |   4
Department2    |   6
```

How should I do it in lambda expressions? Thanks

**Department Class:**

```
public class Department
{
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
    public string Location{ get; set; }

    public virtual List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

Employee Class:

```
 public class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }

    public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: What is the return type of your method?

Comment: And what's the *exact* error message?

Comment: `Cannot implicitly convert type System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#1> to System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<SimpleRMA.Models.Department>. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)` @JonSkeet

Comment: Right, so your `Select` needs to use `new Department { ... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest getting the Departments instead.
It looks like you are using EntityFramework here. Why don't you just do `return Context.Departments.Include("Employees")`. This would give you Collection of Department Objects with Employees filled in. You can get the count of employees in each department by doing departmentObject.Employees.Count().

Comment: Note that you don't need the `()` - just `new Department { ... }` is fine.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks. I would always remember this now that the words come from Jon Skeet himself :)

Comment: Now it returns SimpleRMA does not contain a definition for name.

Comment: I was viewing your profile just now, @JonSkeet. Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: @ImmanuelValle: Well we can't see any of your code using a `Name` property, or anything to do with `SimpleRMA`. This sounds like a completely separate issue, which you should research separately and ask a new question about *if* you can't find a solution yourself.

Comment: @ImmanuelValle Can you Please post your Department class if Intellisense isn't coming to your rescue?

Comment: @ImmanuelValle None of us know that your Employees property was a Collection itself. Everyone here was trying to assign an Integer to that. I'm sorry I didn't ask you for details earlier. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Sorry about that. I'll note that for next time.

Comment: I got it. I just put `item.Employees.Count` in the view. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are return anonymous type which is not supported if you aren't using dynamic keyword as return value. Implement model class like this one and return it.

```
public class DepartmentEmployeesModel
{
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
    public string Employees { get; set; }
}

return Context
         .Employees
         .GroupBy(e => e.DepartmentID)
         .Select(x => new DepartmentEmployeesModel { DepartmentName = x.Key, Employees = x.Count() }).ToList();
```

And change your method signature to

```
IEnumerable<DepartmentEmployeesModel> YourMethodName()
```